# slideToggle <li> by using JS but without unique identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have following HTML code and JS (coffescript) code that doesn't work as expected:

JS Code

```
$(document).ready ->
    $("#description_details").click ->
      $(this).closest('li').next().slideToggle("fast")
```

HTML Code (simple version)

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="description_details">Details</a></li>
  <li id="description_text">some more details</li>
  <li><a href="#" id="description_details">Details</a></li>
  <li id="description_text">some more details</li>
  <li><a href="#" id="description_details">Details</a></li>
  <li id="description_text">some more details</li>
  .
  .
  .
</ul>
```

CSS/SASS

```
#description_text
  display: none
```

My Intension is to toggle alway thes next `li` item, but it only works with the first one. I have no possibility to give an extra class or unique identifier to the `li`items. So I tried it with closest and next, but it only works with the first.

I also can't set the click event on the `li` the Link is in, because there is more text inside.

I would be very thankful for any help!

Comment: you should not use the id attribute here as it should always be unique.

Comment: as @97ldave you should have unique ID, you can not repeat it. so change your ID to class then you can make use of the selector .description_details

Comment: ARGH! unique as the name id says... changed it to class and it works perfect. Thanks very much for the very fast reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard truth: You can't have multiple ID's within your HTML markup. It's invalid and as a result, querying for it will only grab the very first occurence. Thats why you experience the behavior you explained.

You need to get rid of those multiple ID values. Either replace it by *class names* or find another way to correctly *find* / *query* for that `<ul>` element. Maybe by being more specific in a *css selector*, like `"#mycontainer ul li a"`.

Answer (score 0):

as @97ldave mentioned you should have unique ID, you can not repeat it.

so change your ID to class then you can make use of the selector `.description_details`

http://jsfiddle.net/habo/pZKqy/1/